# jQuery(...).autosize is not a function when using autosize.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to get autosize.js to work in my Rails 6 application but it doesn't matter what I try, it's not working.

Every time I try to use it on a textarea I'm getting this error:

> jQuery(...).autosize is not a function

What I did:

I added the plugin via yarn with `yarn add autosize`
Then I required it in my application.js, I tried different solutions:

```
require("autosize")
require("autosize/dist/autosize")
```

Then I imported it in different ways to try if it works somehow (as all other plugins are working).
What I tried:

```
import 'autosize'
import autosize from 'autosize'
```

Then I tried setting a global scope for the variable:

```
global.autosize = autosize;
```

For initialization I followed the readme:

```
autosize($('textarea'));
```

I even tried to remove the yarn package and download the files. But still the same error.

Any more suggestions on what I could do to make it work?

**EDIT:**

Okay, at least I found the problem: The textareas are generated by AJAX, so they are dynamically generated. On other textareas that are not dynamically it's working. 
I tried:

```
$(document).on('focus', 'textarea', function(){
            autosize($('textarea'));
});
```

and visually it's working, but I still get the same error and can't submit the data.

Comment: You call/use  `autosize` on its own, it doesnt make itself a jquery plugin. Eg `autosize(element)`, `autosize.update(element)`, etc

Comment: But I need to define / load it anywhere I guess. Otherwise I get `Uncaught ReferenceError: autosize is not defined`

Comment: There's an [open issue](https://github.com/jackmoore/autosize/issues/377) with `autosize` that might relate to the issue your experiencing.